# Getting total value of an array with condition

Tags: php

I need to get the total value of this array of all the numbers above or equal to 0.
This is the array

```
$aReeks = array(23,245,1,2,12,-10,46,6,66,9999,-55,348,56,6,66,983);
```

This is the code i have so far, but it only shows the highest number of the array and doesnt count the values up and shows the total.

```
$totaal = 0;
      for($y=0; $y < count($aReeks); $y++)
      {
          if($totaal < $aReeks[$y] && $aReeks[$y] > 0)
          $totaal = $aReeks[$y];
      }
```

I have to do it with a for loop.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick way:

```
$total = array_sum(array_filter($aReeks, function($n) { return $n > 0; }));
```

- Filter the array for values greater than 0
- Sum that array

Oh I now see the *"I have to do it with a for loop."*, so this won't be accepted for your homework I imagine.

Answer (score 1):

```
$aReeks = array(23,245,1,2,12,-10,46,6,66,9999,-55,348,56,6,66,983); 

$total=0;
for($i =0 ; $i< count($aReeks) ; $i++)
{
if($aReeks[$i]>=0)
{
    $total+= $aReeks[$i];
}
}
echo $total ;
?>
```

Output

11859

Comment: If the answer is helpful ,then accept it .So that it may be helpful for others.

Answer (score 0):

You are making 2 major mistakes one is in `if` condition which is `$totaal < $aReeks[$y]` you don't need this check at all. Secondly rather than summing up the value of each item to the total of all previous items... you are simply assigning the value to the `$totaal` variable inside the loop.

```
$aReeks = array(23,245,1,2,12,-10,46,6,66,9999,-55,348,56,6,66,983); 
$totaal = 0;
for($y=0; $y < count($aReeks); $y++)
{
    if($aReeks[$y] > 0)
        $totaal = $totaal + $aReeks[$y];
}
```